# can't add item to localstorage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

when adding to localstorage, everything works, but when deleting, the element state is not replaced (the add button does not change)

```
        {window.localStorage.getItem('pokemon').includes(value.name)  ?
        <p 
        className="compareTrue"
        data-name={value.name}
        onClick={(e: MouseEvent<HTMLParagraphElement>) => DPokemon(e.target.dataset.name)}
        >{value.name} added to comparison! </p>
        :
        <p className="compareFalse"
        data-name={value.name}
        onClick={(e: MouseEvent<HTMLParagraphElement>) => setPokemon(e.target.dataset.name)}
        >
         Compare {value.name} from another!
        </p>
        }




    // localStorage set

const setLocalStorage:
(key: string, initial: string) => 
(string | Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>)[]
=(key:string , initial:string) => {
    
    let old_data:any
    let old_dataParse:any
    const [value, setValue]:any = useState(() => {
        return  initial
    })
    useEffect(() => {}, [value])
    console.log(value, 'set')
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        old_data = localStorage.getItem(key)
        old_dataParse = JSON.parse(old_data)
        old_dataParse?.push(value)
        old_dataParse = [...new Set(old_dataParse)]
        if(old_dataParse.length < 4){
            window.localStorage.setItem(key, 
            JSON.stringify(
                old_dataParse.filter(
                    (data:string) => data !== '')))
        }
    }
    return [value , setValue]
}
// localStorage delete
const deleteLocalStorage:
(key: string, initial: string) => 
(string | Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>)[]
=(key:string , initial:string) => {
    let old_data:any
    let old_dataParse:any
    const [value, setValue]:any = useState(() => {
        return  initial
    })
    useEffect(() => {}, [value])
    console.log(value, 'del')
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        old_data = localStorage.getItem(key)
        old_dataParse = JSON.parse(old_data)
        let pokemonFilter = old_dataParse.filter((str:string) =>  str !== value)
        window.localStorage.setItem('pokemon', JSON.stringify(pokemonFilter))
    }
    return [value , setValue]
}



const [pokemonSet, setPokemon] = setLocalStorage('pokemon', '')
const [pokemonD, DPokemon] = deleteLocalStorage('pokemon', '')

useEffect(() => {
    loadData()
}, [pokemonSet,pokemonD])
```

the first click adds to localstorage, the second one removes, the third adds no changes, how to fix it

I'm guessing it's because of useeffect, which doesn't update the state of the object

?[image][image]

state is not updating[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the useState outside of your delete and add functions. When it is declared inside them it only works inside that function. If you declare it outside them then both functions will be able to use the same state.

Not sure why you need those functions anyhow. If i was doing it i would use:

const [state, setState] = React.useState(localStorage.getItem('item') || initial);

use the state then for your page. delete from it or add to it using setState. When you want to save it to local storage just do that. localStorage.setItem('item', state);

Comment: Yes, you're right, something carried me in the wrong place. Thank you!

Comment: no worries. react is tricky stuff at first. good luck.